# How to play an MP3 stream in C#

Tags: c#, audio, mp3, naudio

I want to play an MP3 stream in my C# application. I have a server application that captures wave audio and converts it into MP3, then writes it to a network stream. The client then reads this stream to play the MP3. I have tried NAudio with the following code example, but it results in exception:

```
using (WaveStream blockAlignedStream =
                new BlockAlignReductionStream(
                    WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(
                        new Mp3FileReader(ms))))
            {
                using (WaveOut waveOut = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback()))
                {
                    waveOut.Init(blockAlignedStream);
                    waveOut.Play();                        
                    while (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing )                        
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: what is the exception you see and what line of code?

Comment: basically this code is in loop and run when socket receive new packet after just few itterations "WaveOut device was not close at WaveOut.finalize()" exception came in a messagebox.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.un4seen.com/

bass.dll .NET api

i know its not the answer to your code but its a good music library

Answer (score 1):

I have posted an article on my blog explaining [how to play back an MP3 stream using NAudio](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-play-back-streaming-mp3-using.html). Essentially you have one thread downloading MP3 frames, decompressing them and storing them in a `BufferedWaveProvider`. Another thread then plays back using the `BufferedWaveProvider` as an input.

Comment: Hi sir. I hope you will see this. I tried your example above, but realized that it needs to download the file completely and it starts playing after that. Does NAudio supports real-time playing?