# Playing a MP3 Stream in a C# Application

Tags: c#

Is there a library where I can stream & play the following link (Pause, Play, Forward, Back) full control on song etc and of course playing it..

http://stream.vkdownload.net/cs536519v4/u173702374/cb6a320ef08a.mp3

Thanks! i'm using WinForms C#

Comment: Question may relate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160195/how-to-play-mp3-stream-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

You can use [irrKlang](http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/index.html). It can play alot of sound formats and it can apply effects.

Answer (score -1):

Just add the audio file to your app's resources and use it like that.

```
SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer(YOUR_APP_NAME.Properties.Resources.YOUR_MP3);
sp.Play();
```

Comment: I want to stream it through a web reqeust.

Comment: SoundPlayer doesn't even support MP3.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=vs.110).aspx